# In log4j2 use dynamic filename

Tags: java, log4j2

I am trying to create a dynamic filename for log4j.  I am following the documentation but still getting errors.  I tried different types but the filepath is still invalid?

It looks like the issue is on the logserverdir variable.  I was trying to set the filepath dynamically but I don't have access to the system variables (as this is a web server).  I have access to the code and try to call System setProperties.

I have the following:

Configuration:

```
<File name="MainApiCommonsAppenderApi" fileName="/usr/local/pfs/logs/${main:0}/log4j_api_commons.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] [%X{mdcLogSessionId} - %X{mdcLog}] %-5p - %C{1}.%M(%F:%L) - %m%n"/>     
        </File>
```

And then code:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.MainMapLookup;

        System.setProperty("logserverdir", APPSERVERID);
        final String [] args = {
                "APPSERVERID"
        };
        MainMapLookup.setMainArguments(args);
```

This is the error:

```
[3/20/19 11:53:14:423 EDT] 00000075 SystemOut     O 2019-03-20 11:53:14,421 server.startup : 2 ERROR FileManager (/usr/local/pfs/logs/${main:0}/log4j_api_commons.log) java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:439)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:629)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:654)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.FileUtils.makeParentDirs(FileUtils.java:134)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FileManagerFactory.createManager(FileManager.java:286)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FileManagerFactory.createManager(FileManager.java:274)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:112)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager.getFileManager(FileManager.java:112)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender$Builder.build(FileAppender.java:86)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender$Builder.build(FileAppender.java:51)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:952)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:892)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:884)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:508)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:232)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:244)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:545)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:617)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:634)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:229)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:551)
    at com.ca.apps.shared.rest.init.ApplicationConfigurationLoader.<clinit>(ApplicationConfigurationLoader.java:77)
    at com.ca.apps.shared.rest.init.ApplicationConfigurationLoader.<clinit>(ApplicationConfigurationLoader.java)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1899)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Log4J 2 Lookup values are used in config before they are loaded/present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50405298/log4j-2-lookup-values-are-used-in-config-before-they-are-loaded-present)