# Logging in Grails: reloadable external configuration with Log4j2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, grails, log4j, grails3

I'm trying to configure Grails so as to use external Log4j2 configuration files separating production and development mode. It should listen for configuration changes and refresh it after some period of time.
For Grails 2.x, it can be done by registering `Log4jConfigurer` beans like this:

```
switch (Environment.current) {
   case Environment.PRODUCTION:
      log4jConfigurer(MethodInvokingFactoryBean) {
         targetClass = "org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer"
         targetMethod = "initLogging"
         arguments = ["classpath:ogc-log4j.xml", 30000]
      } 

   case Environment.DEVELOPMENT:
     log4jConfigurer(MethodInvokingFactoryBean) {
        targetClass = "org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer"
        targetMethod = "initLogging"
        arguments = ["classpath:log4j-dev.xml", 30000]
     }
}
```

For some reasons, this approach doesn't work in Grails 3.x. How can I do this in Grails 3.3.3 or in Spring Boot (I guess it should work because Grails 3.x is based on Spring Boot)?

Comment: Do you want to reload the external configuration of Log4j2.

Answer (score 1):

From 3.3.3 of grails

Instead of having it in Java code.
Environment configuration has moved to the YML configuration file.

we can pass different values to different environments and change configuration of log4j

refer to the documentation

[documentaion for Enviroment configuration](https://docs.grails.org/3.3.9/guide/single.html#environments)

Comment: Have you tested it? Because this doesn't work with log4j either. See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11303

Comment: you need to pass different string values to arguments value of l log4jConfigurer

Comment: Okay, it seems like their current bug. I have answered by referring their docs

Answer (score 0):

I reckon we can achieve the desired need with different approaches. As far as I have been aware of externalising `Log4j2` configuration file in Grails 3, we could use either `LogerContext` or `System.setProperty`. The latter could be done as instructed in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862770/log4j2-assigning-file-appender-filename-at-runtime). My suggestion, as well as the demonstration for this question, is to use `LogerContext` as described in [Logging Separation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/logsep.html) section of [Log4j2 manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/).

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false)

        String userHome =  System.getProperty("user.home")
        String pathname = ""
        if (grails.util.Environment.isDevelopmentMode()) {
            pathname = userHome + "/.myConfigurations/log4j2-dev.xml"
        } else {
            pathname = userHome + "/.myConfigurations/log4j2-prod.xml"
        }
        File file = new File(pathname)
        // this will force a reconfiguration
        context.setConfigLocation(file.toURI())
    }
}
```

Please take a look at [my project](https://bitbucket.org/itersdesktop/log4j2withgrails3/) uploaded to Bitbucket. In this project, I tried to log a message after starting the application. The `log.info` was called in `Application.groovy`. Start the application within grails 3.3.9, you will have to run `run-app` to test development or `prod run-app` to test production mode.