# Updating log4j2 appender fileName gives ERROR FileManager java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: java, xml, log4j, log4j2, ioexception

I have a log4j2.xml file that I use to define some loggers that output to .log files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{MM-dd HH:mm:ss  } %p - %m%n"/>
        </Console>

        <File name="LogFileAppender" fileName="${sys:logFileName}" append="false">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d [%t] %p - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
            <AppenderRef ref="LogFileAppender"/>

        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I set the full paths for the logger fileNames in java after the .xml is already read in.

```
public static void initializeLoggers(String logPath)
{
    // set output paths for log files
    System.setProperty("logFileName", logPath + "PROJECT.log");

    // reconfigure loggers with paths
    org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext ctx =
            (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    ctx.reconfigure();
}
```

The code works as expected and logs are output to the updated path, but I am running into these errors below:

> 2022-01-18 15:05:26,685 main ERROR FileManager (${sys:logFileName})
> java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label
> syntax is incorrect  java.io.IOException: The filename, directory
> name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
>
> 2022-01-18 15:05:26,693 main ERROR Could not create plugin of type
> class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender for element
> File:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory
> [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FileManagerFactory@4d826d77]
> unable to create manager for [${sys:logFileName}]  with data
> [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FactoryData@61009542]
> java.lang.IllegalStateException:  ManagerFactory
> [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FileManagerFactory@4d826d77]
> unable to create manager for [${sys:logFileName}]  with data
> [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FactoryData@61009542]
>
> 2022-01-18 15:05:26,699 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender for element File:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender

This is strange since the path I update it to is correct and the resulting logs are output in the desired directory along with all the information inside. No logging happens before initializeLoggers() as well. Any help would be appreciated!
[I referenced this post for the properties updating solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862770/log4j2-assigning-file-appender-filename-at-runtime?rq=1)

Comment: _No logging happens before initializeLoggers()_: yes, but you probably call `LogManager.getLogger` **before**. You can check by setting `-Dlog4j2.loggerContextStacktraceOnStart=true` and `-Dlog4j2.debug=true` as JVM parameters.

Comment: that is probably what is happening since i do define LogManager.getLogger at the top of the class... is there a way to remedy this? do my appenders need a default filename value before getting set in the code? @PiotrP.Karwasz

Answer (score 2):

The code was calling LogManager.getLoggers() before the loggers were initialized with a filename value. I just set the default value like so and the code runs without error now:

```
<File name="LogFileAppender" fileName="${sys:logFileName:-default}" append="false">
    <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d [%t] %p - %m%n</Pattern>
    </PatternLayout>
</File>
```