# Create and add at runtime a custom appender to log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I would need a custom appender for log4j2 that I **programmatically** plug in (I do not want to alter log4j2.xml, as I need that appender to be used by default). For custom appender, there seems to be an answer [How to Create a Custom Appender in log4j2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205093/how-to-create-a-custom-appender-in-log4j2), but how I can add appender at run-ti,e?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699358/log4j-creating-modifying-appenders-at-runtime-log-file-recreated-and-not-appe

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to instantiate the appender and after it plug it into desired log. In this example I am using `ConsoleAppender` and `rootLogger`

```
LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
ConsoleAppender consoleAppender = ConsoleAppender.
              createDefaultAppenderForLayout(PatternLayout.createDefaultLayout());
consoleAppender.start(); // this is optional
config.addAppender(consoleAppender);  // this is optional
ctx.getRootLogger().addAppender(consoleAppender);
ctx.updateLoggers();
```